# How can I debug my complex IF Excel formula?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, formulas

I am a school teacher and am developing my school's assessment system. What should I do to correct this formula?

`=IF(H3="SUR",IF(Subject!C3<2.7,"Not on track",IF(Subject!C3<=3.29,"On track",IF(Subject!C3>=3.3,"Above", IF(H3="MAS",IF(Subject!C3<2.2,"Not on track",IF(Subject!C3<=2.79,"On track",IF(Subject!C3>=2.8,"Above", IF(H3="EXP",IF(Subject!C3<1.7,"Not on track",IF(Subject!C3<=2.29,"On track",IF(Subject!C3>=2.3,"Above",IF(H3="EM3",IF(Subject!C3<1.2,"Not on track",IF(Subject!C3<=1.79,"On track",IF(Subject!C3>=1.8,"Above", IF(H3="EM2",IF(Subject!C3<0.7,"Not on track",IF(Subject!C3<=1.29,"On track",IF(Subject!C3>=1.3,"Above",IF(H3="EM1",IF(Subject!C3<0.23,"Not on track",IF(Subject!C3<=0.42,"On track",IF(Subject!C3>=0.43,"Above"))))))))))))))))))))))))`

The result is dependent upon what is entered within H_, and each category has specific ranges.

Comment: what should happen when h3="sur" holds true? I dont see it in your formula. You have a bunch of nested IFs but the else is missing looks like. You should use notepad++ to format such a long formula in several lines and match parenthesis.

Comment: When H3 = SUR...
AND
C3 <2.69 (should display "Not on track")
C3 =<3.3 (should display "On track")
C3 >=3.31 (should display "Above")

Comment: I think you should use a lookup table instead of nested ifs.

Comment: Please could I have some guidance with this?
I have been assigned this mammoth task when fully known I am not an experienced wizard...

Comment: Basically I need the following formula:
H3 = SUR
AND
IF Subject!C3 <2.7,"Not on track"
IF Subject!C3 <=3.3,"On track"
IF Subject!C3 >3.31,"Above".

Answer (score 3):

As was said in the comments, create a table:

[image]

Then you would use the following Array formula:

```
=INDEX(O:O,MATCH(C3,IF($M$1:$M$18=H3,$N$1:$N$18)))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

Each group needs to be together and in ascending order for this method to work.

It does allow the change of criteria and output without changing the hard coded formula.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, however how would this be altered concerning whether H3 has different entry such as SUR,EXP,EM1,EM2 and EM3?

Comment: It doesn't get altered at all, it will find the correct output with the given thresholds.  Just change H3 to any of the choices and it will use those numbers as the threshold. @OllieW.  On formula to rule them all.

Comment: Feel like such a noob.. SO I just enter every possibility?

Comment: Yes,  Put 2.2 in C3 and change H3 from SUR to MAS and the cell will change from `Not on Track` to `On Track` @OllieW

Comment: And any of the `EM`s will become `Above` for the same number.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to help yourself in 3 steps.

**Step 1** - Enlarge the formula bar so it contains more than 1 row:
[image]
**Step 2** - Use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to make the formula understandable:
[image]
**Step 3** - On the Excel ribbon, go to `Formulas` > `Evaluate Formula` and press evaluate:
[image]

Good luck, have fun! :)

Answer (score 1):

It should be two separate lookups, because the text lookup is exact and the number lookup is approximate. If for example if you have this in the range `A1:D6` :

```
EM1     0.23    0.43    Exp
EM2     0.7     1.3     2
EM3     1.2     1.8
EXP     1.7     2.3
MAS     2.2     2.8
SUR     2.7     3.3
```

Then `=VLOOKUP("EXP",A1:C6,2,0)` results in 1.7 and `=VLOOKUP("EXP",A1:C6,3,0)` in 2.3

```
=IF(D2 < VLOOKUP(D1, A1:C6, 2, 0), "Not on track",
 IF(D2 < VLOOKUP(D1, A1:C6, 3, 0), "On track", "Above"))
```

[image]