# Index Match Works on some cells, not others

Tags: excel

I was using this Index Match formula with no issues:
=INDEX('Rain Data For 9 Stations'!A:S,MATCH(RainWICSProximity!J100,'Rain Data For 9 Stations'!A:A,0),INDEX($N$4:$N$12,MATCH(H100,$M$4:$M$12,0)))

I added more data, and it now only returns some values, while returning #N/A for others, even though there is a value to return.

Comment: Just a thought, did you try entering it as an array formula?

Comment: I tried that as well, no luck on the values that are still returning #N/A

Comment: Please explain in words what you are trying to do because it isn't clear from your formula

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Index returns the value in a range.

What you are doing is `=INDEX(MATCH(),INDEX(MATCH()))`. It works due to some luck, because sometimes the second `Index()` returns cell with value as well. However, if the second index returns cell with an empty value, then the first index has to return something like `=Index(4,0)`, which is `#N/A`.

In general, try `=Index(Match(),Match())`.

To see where exactly the error is, select the cell with the formula, go to the Excel ribbon >Formulas>Evaluate Formula.
Then press a few times **Evaluate Formula** and see what happens:

[image]

[See this answer for step-by-step formula evaluation.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43744608/5448626)

Comment: So it would be:=INDEX('Rain Data For 9 Stations'!A:S,MATCH(RainWICSProximity!J100,'Rain Data For 9 Stations'!A:A,0),MATCH($N$4:$N$12,MATCH(H100,$M$4:$M$12,0))) ?

Comment: hm, I tried 
=INDEX('Rain Data For 9 Stations'!A:J,MATCH(E2,'Rain Data For 9 Stations'!A:A,0),MATCH(G2,'Rain Data For 9 Stations'!A:J,0)), still no luck, but this solution does seem to be the proper way to do it

Comment: @user7618007 - see the edit of my answer, you will find out where the error is.

Answer (score 1):

@Vityata was correct, Index, Match, Match works wonderfully, also, my original formula does work.

The issue was, I had calculate set to Manual, not auto, in excel settings.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to expand your range. I am not real familiar with Index Match but trying to learn to use it more, but I believe it is kind of like VLOOKUP. Your ranges    $N$4:$N$12 and     $M$4:$M$12 is where it is looking right? If so, those ranges are not expanding even though you added more data. So you need to expand it to like $M$4:$M$100 or whatever. Or expand it to find the last row which is what I usually do. like mine would be "$M$4:$M" & LastRow & "" or something like that.

Comment: Hmm it looks like Vityata probably has the correct answer I didn't notice the double Index. I am still new at this but trying to help : ) So my answer may not even make sense.