# Why does my INDEX formula no longer work?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I created a formula that worked for some time that does this.
search cell x for UID found in list b and if something is found, display UID, kinda deal.
I have a team list (TEAM) with UIDs (on rows A2 - A32) and if one of these UIDs is found in a cell I need to report it.
Here is my formula:

```
=INDEX(TEAM!$A$2:$A$32,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TEAM!$A$2:$A$32,S2)),0))
```

I am unsure as to why it stopped working and after spending SO much time searching around, I finally come to the pros.

Comment: See how to debug an Excel formula here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/43744608/5448626

Comment: you say list b... shouldn't this range `SEARCH(TEAM!$A$2:$A$32...` point to another list than the UID list? so is this part correct? Anyway I would appreciate if you create mock example with some data. It's easier to see how the formula behaves/expected result.

Comment: Put your some of sample data.

Comment: Perhaps you weren't aware that it is an array formula, at one point edited it and then forgot to re-commit it with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER.

Comment: Thank you XOR LX, that was exactly it...sigh. Back to business